# how to pass a connection to Mybatis

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mybatis, isolation-level

in a project I need to set the transaction isolation level to SNAPSHOT,
I know that it is possible to set it in java with

```
System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

// STEP 4: Execute a query
System.out.println("Creating statement...");
conn.setTransactionIsolation(4096);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

unfortunately I didn't find this possibility in Mybatis so is there a way to pass Mybatis a jdbc connection on which I already have setted it to this isolation level?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs, but you could for example:

- set the default transaction isolation level directly in the database and don't bother with the setting in Java;
- you could create yourself a `DataSource` that before returning a connection sets the desired isolation level on it. You can then configure it in the [environment](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#environments) instead of those MyBatis provides;
- in some circumstances [MyBatis allows you to specify a connection or the isolation level](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html#SqlSessionFactory) when opening a session. You might want to read the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf) to see what your options are.

Answer (score 0):

You might extend [JdbcTransactionFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ibatis/ibatis-sqlmap/3.0-beta-8/org/apache/ibatis/transaction/jdbc/JdbcTransactionFactory.java) as well [JdbcTransaction](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ibatis/ibatis-sqlmap/3.0-beta-8/org/apache/ibatis/transaction/jdbc/JdbcTransaction.java#JdbcTransaction) class and pass any parameters you like as stated in [documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html):

> could put your own fully qualified class name or Type Alias that
>   refers to your own implementation of the TransactionFactory interface
>
> Any properties configured in the XML will be passed to the
>   setProperties() method after instantiation

```
<transactionManager type="com.example.CustomTansactionFactory">
  <property name="isolationLevel" value="4096"/>
</transactionManager>
```

> Using these two interfaces, you can completely customize how MyBatis
>   deals with Transactions.

```
public class CustomTansactionFactory extends JdbcTransactionFactory {
  ...
  public Transaction newTransaction(Connection conn, boolean autoCommit) {
    return new CustomJdbcTransaction(conn, autoCommit, isolationLevel);
  }
  ...
}
```